# Trying to shorten code in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

One of my assignments in vb.net is to make a program that takes in 15 inputted "test scores", returns the average, and then returns the corresponding letter grade. I am trying to make this as short as possible, and I remembered a code format that I can use when I am coding in Python (simple example with only three scores):

```
counter = 0
number = 0
test1,test2,test3 = 0,0,0
for i in [test1,test2,test3]:
    print("Enter a test score")
    i = int(input())
    counter += i
    number += 1
average = counter/number
```

Is there such a code format in VB.NET?

Comment: SO is not here to teach you how to code in VB.  It is for help with specific code issues.  It's for you to learn what VB can do and then do what you think you need to to accomplish your aim.  If that doesn't work, show us what you did and tell us how it doesn't meet your needs. That's what SO is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Here is a simple sample code which asks user to input number of items and then items one by one. At the end it calculates average of numbers.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Items")
Dim numberOfItems As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), numberOfItems) Then
    Dim items As New List(Of Decimal)()
    For i As Integer = 1 To numberOfItems
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number {0}", i)
        Dim num As Decimal
        If Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), num) Then
            items.Add(num)
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Average is " + items.Average())
    Console.ReadLine()
End If
```

Please note that I've not included any type of error handling.